# Issue with Wix 4.1 Worker Service installer dll not found

Tags: installation, wix, worker, asp.net-core-6.0

I am getting error when doing installation with wix 4.1

Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: WixLearning.exe
Path: C:\Program Files\WixTutorial\Joke Service\WixLearning.exe
Message: The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\Program Files\WixTutorial\Joke
Service\WixLearning.dll'.

[image]

This is how the wix project looks like

Package.wxs

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!-- Define the variables in "$(var.*) expressions" -->
 <?define Name = "Joke Service" ?>
 <?define Manufacturer = "WixTutorial" ?>
 <?define Version = "1.0.0" ?>
 <?define UpgradeCode = "9ED3FF33-8718-444E-B44B-69A2344B7E98" ?>

 <Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Package Name="$(Name)"
         Manufacturer="$(Manufacturer)"
         Version="$(Version)"
         UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
         Compressed="true">

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="Main" Title="WixLearning Setup">
    <ComponentRef  Id="ServiceExecutable" />
  </Feature>
 </Package>
</Wix>
```

Folder.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)">
        <!-- This will create a subdirectory inside INSTALLFOLDER called "SubDirectory" 
   -->
        <Directory Id="PRODUCTDIRECTORY" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)" />
    </Directory>
  </StandardDirectory>
 </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

ExampleComponent.wxs

```
      <!-- Create a single component which is the App.WindowsService.exe file -->
      <Component Id="ServiceExecutable" Bitness="always64">

          <!-- Copies the App.WindowsService.exe file using the
                 project reference preprocessor variables -->
          <File Id="WixLearning.exe"
                Source="$(var.WixLearning.TargetDir)publish\WixLearning.exe"
                KeyPath="true" />

          <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
          <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />

          <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
          <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                          Type="ownProcess"
                          Name="WixLearning"
                          DisplayName="WixLearning"
                          Description="A joke service that periodically logs nerdy humor."
                          Start="auto"
                          ErrorControl="normal" />

          <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
          <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                          Start="install"
                          Stop="both"
                          Remove="uninstall"
                          Name="WixLearning"
                          Wait="true" />
      </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
```